# Google visualization chart average number of sale types by year

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have the following dataTable:

```
var dataTableSales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Sale Date', 'Sale Type'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale']
]);
```

What I want to do is chart the average number of 'cash sale' Sale Types for each year. I can easily get a dataTable with the total number of sales for all Sale Types per year as follows:

```
var groupedData = google.visualization.data.group(
    dataTableSales,
    [ { column: 2, modifier: getYearForRow, type: 'string', label: 'Year' } ],
    [ { column: 6, aggregation: google.visualization.data.count, type: 'number', label: 'Total Sales' } ] );
```

Is this possible by using a group? If not what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have the counts by year, `group` the data using...

`google.visualization.data.avg`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataTableSales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Sale Date', 'Sale Type'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale']
  ]);
  dataTableSales.sort({column: 0});

  // build view and aggregation columns
  var viewColumns = [{
    label: 'Year',
    type: 'string',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 0).getFullYear().toString();
    }
  }];
  var avgColumns = [];
  var sumColumns = [];
  var saleTypes = dataTableSales.getDistinctValues(1);
  saleTypes.forEach(function (saleType) {
    var colIndex = viewColumns.push({
      label: saleType,
      type: 'number',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) === saleType) ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });
    avgColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg,  // <-- avg aggregation
      column: colIndex - 1,
      label: saleType,
      type: 'number'
    });
    sumColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: colIndex - 1,
      label: saleType,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTableSales);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var sum = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    sumColumns
  );

  var avg = google.visualization.data.group(
    sum,
    [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Average';}}],
    avgColumns
  );

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    dataTable: avg
  });
  table.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

to get average sales by type per year...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataTableSales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Sale Date', 'Sale Type'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 'financed'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'leased'],
    [new Date(2016, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 'cash sale']
  ]);
  dataTableSales.sort({column: 0});

  // build view and aggregation columns
  var viewColumns = [{
    label: 'Year',
    type: 'string',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 0).getFullYear().toString();
    }
  }];
  var sumColumns = [];
  var saleTypes = dataTableSales.getDistinctValues(1);
  saleTypes.forEach(function (saleType) {
    var colIndex = viewColumns.push({
      label: saleType,
      type: 'number',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) === saleType) ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });
    sumColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: colIndex - 1,
      label: saleType,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });
  var colIndex = viewColumns.push({
    label: 'total',
    type: 'number',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return 1;
    }
  });
  sumColumns.push({
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    column: colIndex - 1,
    label: 'total',
    type: 'number'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTableSales);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var sum = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    sumColumns
  );

  var avgColumns = [0];
  for (var i = 1; i < sum.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; i++) {
    // use function to lock the value of --> i
    addAvgCol(i);
  }

  function addAvgCol(colIndex) {
    avgColumns.push({
      label: sum.getColumnLabel(colIndex),
      type: sum.getColumnType(colIndex),
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var typeAvg;
        if (dt.getValue(row, sum.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) !== 0) {
          typeAvg = dt.getValue(row, colIndex) / dt.getValue(row, sum.getNumberOfColumns() - 1);
        } else {
          typeAvg = null;
        }
        return typeAvg;
      }
    });
  }

  var viewAvg = new google.visualization.DataView(sum);
  viewAvg.setColumns(avgColumns);

  var tableSum = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_sum',
    dataTable: sum
  });
  tableSum.draw();

  var tableAvg = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_avg',
    dataTable: viewAvg
  });
  tableAvg.draw();
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Sum</div>
<div id="table_sum"></div>
<div>Avg</div>
<div id="table_avg"></div>
```

Comment: That's close but I need the averages for each year. I guess I would have to get distinct years then for each year get the average as you have done?

Comment: yea, that's where i got lost, you want the average sales for a specific category? such as `'cash sale'`? if so, 5 sold in 2016, what would the average be?

Comment: I need to know for example what the average number of sales that are 'cash' in a given year. So for example in 2016 there were 12 sales, and 4 of them were 'cash' so on average 33% of sales were 'cash' in 2016. Sorry, I am also having a hard wrapping my head around how to do this using dataTables.

Comment: don't apologize, i get it -- see __EDIT__ above, for average for each type per year -- not sure if most efficient but should work...